# undefined method in Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, module

I have a /lib/custom

inside I have custom.rb and custom_page.rb

custom.rb

```
require 'custom_page.rb'

    module Custom

     def self.name(params)
      # logic
     end

    end
```

I've added in application.rb         `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

I can't seem to call in my controllers to `Custom.name(params)`

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for Custom:Module
```

I've tried with define the method as `def Custom.name`, using `class << self` and `method_function :name` yet nothing helps..

Am I missing something?

Comment: is that really what's in your custom.rb ? It's not valid ruby as is and should raise a syntax error

Comment: no it is not, I tried to simplify it

Comment: What about `Custom::name`?

Comment: @zishe that doesn't work either

Comment: you code valid expect `require`. http://repl.it/USi

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the Rails naming convention. In your rails console, try

```
irb(main):001:0> Custom::Custom
LoadError: Expected lib/custom/custom.rb to define Custom::Custom
```

Rais expects you do define `module Custom::Custom` **(not `module Custom`)** in `lib/custom/custom.rb`.

Rails sees a folder `lib/custom` and created an empty module `Custom` **(doesn't respond to `name` method)** based on convention, if you want to define module `Custom`, you have to write a file `lib/custom.rb`

The convention is

```
lib/custom.rb #define module Custom
lib/custom/deeper.rb #define module Custom::Deeper
lib/empty_folder/ # rails provides you an empty module EmptyFolder
```

BTW you don't have to `require 'custom_page'` in your `custom.rb`, if Rails sees CustomPage in your code, it will try to load the class definition file based on naming convention, given that your `custom_page.rb` file path follows the convention.

Comment: another thing to highlight is, without fixing your code, after you tried `Custom::Custom` in Rails console, you try again `Custom.name`, it will show positive result. Because it forced Rails to read `lib/custom/custom.rb` and added the method `name` to existing module `Custom`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ActiveSupport::Concern` to extend both class and instance methods.  In the module just to this:

```
module Custom
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # everything but the class methods go here
  end

  module ClassMethods
    # define class methods here
    def name(params)
      #logic
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `Custom` module still haven't `name` method. This feature extend class methods.